# Creating a direction from a SharePoint Online Home Page to A SharePoint Communication Page

Tags: redirect

I am having difficulty in redirecting my SharePoint Online Homepage to a a new communications page I created. Can someone please help me with a script that works? All the scripts I have inputted into the Web part do not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place this code in a script editor web part, or create a .html file in the site assets library and then use a content editor webpart and link to the .html file and this code will execute and redirect. obviously changing the window.open parameter to your communications site.

`<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('http://siteYouWantToRedirectToURL.com')
</script>`

Comment: Thank you so very  much! It worked!!

Comment: Please mark this as answered, glad it worked for you :)

Comment: Sorry how do I do that? I am new here. Thanks

Comment: There should be a green check mark next to my answer or something to indicate that it is correct. LOL sorry I am somewhat new as well :)

Comment: Maybe under the down arrow, there should be a green check I believe.